# Limitar consulta foreach

Tags: laravel, foreach

Como puedo limitar un @foreach ?
uso un foreach para mostrar los datos de una tabla relacionada y me gustaría limitar los resultados de ese foreach intento usar esto pero me da error

```
{{$count = 0;}}  @foreach($product->post as $produc)  {{if($count == 4) break; }}

///contenido

{{$count++;}}
```

alguna idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes lograrlo con [@break](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#loops):

```
@php
$count = 0;
@endphp

@foreach($product->post as $produc)

    @break($count == 4)

    ///contenido

    @php
    $count++;
    @endphp

@endforeach
```

Pero como alternativa podrías usar:

```
@foreach($product->post as $count => $produc)

    @break($count == 4)

    ///contenido

@endforeach
```

Comment: si gracias la alternativa va perfecto

Answer (score 0):

Si `$count` siempre es un numero, yo te plantearia que en el controlador dividieras ese array de resultados en arrays de ese tamaño. Luego le pasarias a la plantilla el primer array.

ejemplo:

```
$count = 4;
$resultados = ['a', 'b, 'c', 'd', 'e','f,','g','h'];

$listas = array_chunk ($resultados, $count, true);
```

Ahora, en $lista tienes un array de arrays. El primer array tiene los 4 primeros elementos, el segundo los 4 segundos, y asi sucesivamente.

```
$productos = $listas[0]; // ahora tienes los 4 primeros en $productos.
```

manda $productos a tu plantilla e iteralos en el foreach.